# Unable to load file or assembly 'PcapDotNet.Core.dll'

Tags: c#, dependencies, visual-studio-2017, filenotfoundexception, pcap.net

I had a working Solution on my computer using "visual studio community" and a win7 x32 install. (it uses PcapDotNet package)
I migrated my system to another computer and installed a win7 x64.
Now, my program using the PcapDotNet package does not work anymore.

Error : `System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Unable to load file or assembly 'PcapDotNet.Core.dll' or one of its dependency.`

I tried to change package AND target builds to x64 but still, have the same issue...

The four required DLLs are well into both Debug and Release folders with the .exe file.

```
PcapDotNet.Base.dll
PcapDotNet.Core.dll
PcapDotNet.Core.Extensions.dll
PcapDotNet.Packets.dll
```

I even tried to target the newest Framework 4.6.1, and it didn't changes anything.

Does anyone have any idea of what to do about it, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `depends` tool to check the dependencies of your DLL. Then you can cross-check whether all dependencies are present.

The tool is available here:
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Oh yea! you are my time saver! I was missing an installation of `WinPCap for windows`

Comment: hey what if I already installed WinPCap, but the error still occurs??

Answer (score 0):

Are the dlls referenced in the solution? My suggestion is to have them in a separate folder (inside or outside your solution folder), reference them in the solution (from the new path) and after that select them and open the properties tool window. There set CopyLocal to true. 
Hope this helps.